# Is $f(x)=\frac{|x|^2}{x}$ continuous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, functions, continuity

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{|x|^2}{x},  & \text{if $x \neq 0$} \\
0, & \text{if $x=0$}
\end{cases}$$

Can someone please explain if f is continuous? Assume $x$ is a complex number

Hints would do

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, if you check the limit from both left and right you have the limits both equal to 0. Note that continuous is different from differentiable. And if you don't have any typo your function is essentially just $f(x)=x$ so it is both continuous and differentiable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any complex number you have $|x|^2=x\cdot\overline{x}$, where $\overline{x}$ denotes the [complex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate).

Now if you notice that
$$\frac{|x|^2}x=\frac{x\cdot\overline{x}}x=\overline{x}$$
then you can see that $$f(x)=\overline{x}.$$

It is relatively easy to see that this function (complex conjugation) is continuous at every point $x\in\mathbb C$. (It is simply the function $a+bi \mapsto a-bi$, i.e., reflection w.r.t. real axis.)

Answer (score 0):

Let $\delta = \epsilon \gt 0$ such that $0<|x| \lt \delta$ then $0 \lt |x| = \frac {|x|^2}{|x|} = |\frac {|x|^2}{|x|}-0 | \lt \delta = \epsilon$

Hence $f(0) = 0$